# Прототип класса с динамическим массивом. Перегрузка оператора сложения

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы, перегрузка-операторов

Пытался написать класс с динамическими массивами (дальше это буду распараллеливать). Определил конструктор и деструктор:

---

```
    class massive_thread
{
    public:
    int row;
    double *mass;
    massive_thread(int r)
    {
        row = r;
        mass = new double[r];
        cout << this << "- Construct\n";
    }
    void display()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            cout << mass[i] << ' ';
        cout << "\n_______________\n";
    }
    const massive_thread operator+(const massive_thread& right_part) const
    {
        massive_thread out(row);
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)  
            out.mass[i] = mass[i] + right_part.mass[i];
        return out;
    }
    ~massive_thread()
    {
        delete[] mass;
        cout << this << "- Destroy\n";
    }
    void ones()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            mass[i] = 1.0;
    }

    void random(int start, int stop)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            mass[i] = start + (stop - start) * (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    }
};
```

Там еще определены методы ones и random. При попытке сложить массивы:

```
    massive_thread m1(5);
    massive_thread m2(5);
    massive_thread m3(5);
    m1.ones();
    m2.random(0,1);
    m3 = m1 + m2;
    m1.display();
    m2.display();
    m3.display();
```

На выходе я получаю следующее:

```
1 1 1 1 1 
_______________
0.840188 0.394383 0.783099 0.79844 0.911647 
_______________
0 1.39438 1.7831 1.79844 1.91165
```

---

Если посмотреть на конструкторы и деструкторы.

```
0x7ffc5d45f360- Construct
0x7ffc5d45f370- Construct
0x7ffc5d45f380- Construct

вход в метод
0x7ffc5d45f390- Construct

выход из метода
0x7ffc5d45f390- Destroy
 выход из main
0x7ffc5d45f380- Destroy 
0x7ffc5d45f370- Destroy
0x7ffc5d45f360- Destroy
```

То в начале создается три объекта, что логично. Далее создается конструктор внутри метода класса. Далее этот объект удаляется. Разве он не должен был скопироваться побитово и только потом отработать деструктор? Но получается, что первый элемент нулевой(не зависит от размера). В чем тут дело?

Comment: Если не прописывать деструктор таким образом, то произойдет утечка памяти

Comment: вам следует определить конструктор по-умолчанию, определить или запретить копирующий / перемещающий конструкторы и операторы присваивания и начать использовать `std::unique_ptr` для управления память.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Разве он не должен был скопироваться побитово и только потом отработать деструктор?

Он действительно скопировался, а потом был удален. Но в этом и заключается ошибка.

После копирования, указатели `m3.mass` и `out.mass` указывают на один и тот же блок памяти. Затем вызов деструктора на `out` удаляет этот блок памяти. А после этого в `m3.display();` вы читаете из этого удаленного блока, что вызывает неопределенное поведение. Дальше еще хуже - в деструкторе `m3` вы удаляете уже удаленный блок - снова неопределенное поведение.

---

Нормально управлять памятью в своем классе с непривычки сложно. (Как и другими ресурсами, которые создаются и освобождаются вручную, вроде `FILE *`.)

Именно поэтому самое простое и правильное решение - вместо сырых `new/delete` использовать стандартные контейнеры (в вашем случае `std::vector`) или умные указатели.

---

Но если вы хотите управлять памятью/ресурсами вручную, приготовьтесь разбирать простыню текста. :)

Для начала, вам нужно очень хорошо понять ["правило трех, пяти и нуля"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three):

> В большинстве случаев в классе должны быть переопределены либо:
>
> - Одновременно деструктор, копирующий конструктор, и копирующий оператор присваивания (три).
> - Одновременно деструктор, копирующий конструктор, копирующий оператор присваивания, перемещающий конструктор и перемещающий оператор присваивания (пять).
> - Ничего из вышеперечисленного (ноль).

Последний вариант - самый удобный, потому что безопасный. Вы могли бы использовать его, если бы взяли `std::vector`. Но раз вы используете `new/delete`, он очевидно не подходит.

У вас в коде нарушается правило трех - деструктор есть, но недостает как минимум копирующих конструктора и оператора присваивания (а в идеале еще и перемещающих конструктора и оператора присваивания - часто они могут ускорить программу, но об этом потом).

Добавим копирующий конструктор и оператор присваивания:

```
massive_thread(const massive_thread &other) : massive_thread(other.row)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        mass[i] = other.mass[i];
}

massive_thread &operator=(massive_thread other) noexcept
{
    std::swap(row, other.row);
    std::swap(mass, other.mass);
    return *this;
}
```

Теперь программа работает как надо:

> ```
> 0x7ffcc8b8e770- Construct
> 0x7ffcc8b8e760- Construct
> 0x7ffcc8b8e750- Construct
> 0x7ffcc8b8e780- Construct
> 0x7ffcc8b8e780- Destroy
> 1 1 1 1 1 
> _______________
> 0.840188 0.394383 0.783099 0.79844 0.911647 
> _______________
> 1.84019 1.39438 1.7831 1.79844 1.91165 
> _______________
> 0x7ffcc8b8e750- Destroy
> 0x7ffcc8b8e760- Destroy
> 0x7ffcc8b8e770- Destroy
> ```

Теперь копирующий конструктор, вместо того, чтобы просто копировать все поля без изменений, создает новый блок памяти через `new[]` (с помощью конструктора `massive_thread(int r)`), и копирует в него все числа.

Обратите внимание, копирующий оператор присваивания написан необычно: это называется ["copy & swap idiom"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).

По сути, copy & swap - это универсальный способ писать полностью безопасный оператор присваивания. Запомните его, и вам больше никогда (или почти никогда) не нужно будет думать, что писать в операторах присваивания. Очень удобно!

(Кое-кто говорит, что операторы присваивания, написанные обычным способом, могут быть чуть быстрее, но их намного сложнее написать правильно, так что я бы не заморачивался.)

---

Программа работает, но остается простор для оптимизации:

Результат `m1 + m2` *копируется* в `m3`, а потом оригинал удаляется. То есть вы создаете новый блок памяти через `new[]`, копируете в него числа из старого блока, а затем удаляете старый блок.

Это неразумно, ведь если старый объект всегда удаляется, можно было бы просто использовать тот же самый блок памяти в новом объекте. Как раз этого можно достичь, написав перемещающий конструктор.

Грубо говоря, перемещающие конструкторы обычно срабатывают (вместо копирующих конструкторов) когда исходный объект - временный, то есть скоро будет удален. С перемещающими операторами присваивания все аналогично.

(Советую почитать про категории выражений ("value categories"), про rvalue-ссылки (`&&`) и про `std::move`. Тогда станет понятно, какие конструкторы когда вызываются, и почему.)

Добавим перемещающий конструктор:

```
massive_thread(massive_thread &&other) noexcept :
    row(std::exchange(other.row, 0)), mass(std::exchange(other.mass, nullptr)) {}
```

Перемещающие конструкторы почти всегда можно писать одним и тем же способом, с помощью `std::exchange`. Тут думать почти не нужно.

Обычно нам также потребовался бы перемещающий оператор присваивания, но так как мы используем copy & swap, он не нужен. Сopy & swap присваивание работает как копирующее, если у вас есть копирующий конструктор, и одновременно как перемещающее, если у вас есть перемещающий конструктор.

Также, чтобы получить перемещение вместо копирования, вам нужно убрать `const` из возвращаемого типа `operator+`:

```
/*const*/ massive_thread operator+(const massive_thread& right_part) const
```

Константные объекты обычно не могут быть перемещены, поэтому возвращать константные объекты без всякой необходимости - очень плохая привычка. Это замедляет вашу программу просто так, не принося никакой пользы.

---

Дальше. Вы наверное заметили, что мы отметили перемещающий конструктор и универсальный оператор присваивания как `noexcept`.

Казалось бы, зачем, если и так понятно, что они не могут выбросить исключения? Это желательно делать потому, что вы можете захотеть хранить ваш класс в стандартных контейнерах (вроде `std::vector`). Отсутствие `noexcept` не вызовет ошибку, но может замедлить программу.

Стандартные контейнеры (вроде `std::vector`) для безопасности часто [брезгуют](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001823/how-to-enforce-move-semantics-when-a-vector-grows) использовать перемещающие конструкторы и операторы присваивания своих элементов (и используют вместо этого копирующие), если те не отмечены как `noexcept`.

---

Также, советую почитать про [scope guard'ы](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjTrfoiB0MQ). Они очень помогают в безопасном управлении ресурсами, особенно если одному классу требуется контролировать несколько ресурсов.

Все. Кто осилил - молодец.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!